# How to use forge coverage effectively?

Tags: testing, foundry, unittesting, forge

I am trying to get the test coverage for our Smart Contracts. Couple of questions I have.

1. While running the coverage command, it doesn't include all the test cases in the folder, is it because we have written test cases in a modular form, i.e. there are folders inside folders and then test cases, so that the structure remains clean when the codebase grows.

**The files included in the report:**
[image]

**The actual files I have:**

[image]

2. While using the `--report summary` flag it creates a JSON file that is not practically readable to a human eye, what is the best way to extract the details given in that JSON file?

**JSON File :**

[image]

3. Lastly, are there some docs, etc. for more information on the usage of forge coverage, as the foundry book is pretty limited.

Comment: Thanks for posting, in the future, please refrain from taking screenshots and instead post markdown formatted code. You can view this link for more information: https://github.com/Cyfrin/security-and-auditing-full-course-s23/blob/main/how-to-ask-a-question.md

Comment: Can you try renaming the`testFoundry` folder to `test`

Comment: I've already done that @PatrickCollins, the output is the same. I'm confused, about how to interpret the output. The table includes the contracts as well as some test files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers below refer to **forge 0.2.0**, the latest release at the time of the writing.

```bash
foundryup: installed - forge 0.2.0 (2b2a499 2024-01-31T17:41:20.967549332Z)
foundryup: installed - cast 0.2.0 (2b2a499 2024-01-31T17:41:20.972189858Z)
foundryup: installed - anvil 0.2.0 (2b2a499 2024-01-31T17:41:20.965275165Z)
foundryup: installed - chisel 0.2.0 (2b2a499 2024-01-31T17:41:20.969731196Z)
```

#### 1. Running tests to get the coverage

The coverage operation executes all the tests in the test files, including those in subfolders of the `test` folder. But you need to put the tests in the `test` folder (or subfolders) and the source to be tested in the `src` folder (or subfolders).

When working correctly, what you see in the report generated by the `forge coverage` command are the results of testing the source code files present in the `src` folder running the tests in the `test` folder.

You should not see the file containing the tests listed in that report.

In your case, looking at the screenshot, I see the test cases files (`.t.sol`) listed in the report, so it means Forge thinks those files must also be included in the coverage report. And as a side note, nothing is executing tests over the test files, so this is the reason why you get 0% for those files.

You need to fix your project structure: remove those test files from being the target of the coverage, put them under a dedicated `test` folder, move the source code under a `src` folder, change the importing path accordingly to find the source `.sol` contracts again.

You project should look something like this:

```
/src/contracts/PushComm/PushCommV2_5.sol
...
/test/BaseTest.t.sol
/test/PushCore/...
...
/foundry.toml
/README.md
...
```

Using the `src` folder as the root folder for your code and the `test` folder on the same level for the test case is a best practice, but you can change that editing the `foundry.toml` configuration file; still, I suggest sticking with the best practices to have fewer problems with the repo maintenance.

```
[profile.default]
src = "src"
out = "out"
libs = ["lib"]
```

See more [config options at the official repo](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/blob/master/crates/config/README.md#all-options).

#### 2. Coverage reporting options

I'm not sure how you produced that JSON, but the coverage `--report` option works like this:

- **summary**: the default output in the form of a table with colors and data
- **lcov**: coverage in [LCOV](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Lcov) format; you can use multiple tools to decode that info (i.e., [generating HTML reports](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/genhtml.1.html) from that) and also dedicated VS Code plugins like [Coverage Gutters](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryanluker.vscode-coverage-gutters)
- **debug**: text format, with some details about the uncovered code parts and what's happening under the hood
- **bytecode**: it does not work correctly for me, and I see [I'm not alone having issues](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/issues/6875), and [this value is not mentioned in the doc](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/forge/forge-coverage#forge-coverage) even if it's already mentioned in the command options, so I suggest not to use it until it is stable.

#### 3. Documentation and tutorials

Official documentation is not super detailed, but you can find on the Internet articles like [this one from Rohanzarathustra](https://medium.com/@rohanzarathustra/forge-coverage-overview-744d967e112f), that let you play around with all the possibilities of the coverage command.

Please consider the program is labelled `0.2` for a reason, so expect improvements, changes and breaking changes in the future. ;)